# Why won't my breaker reset after it tripped, even with no devices connected?

Tags: receptacle

One of our kitchen outlets made a pop when my wife unplugged an item from it. The breaker tripped and now won't reset after I unplugged everything on that circuit. Is the outlet bad and not allowing the circuit to close causing the breaker to not reset? Or is the breaker need replacing?

Comment: It would be impossible to tell without troubleshooting.  Have you inspected the outlet, and inspected the wiring within the outlet's junction box?  Is it a GFCI outlet?

Comment: If it is a breaker in the panel, then it should reset, it might trip right away if there is a problem in the circuit.  If the breaker does not reset then replace with the same.

Comment: Are you sure you're resetting it properly? You need to turn it _off_ first.

Answer (score 1):

It could be the breaker or the receptacle. More *likely* is the receptacle. But since this is a kitchen, unless it is *decades* old and never updated, the key issue first is the GFCI. So starting point is:

- Do you have a GFCI/breaker - a breaker with a "TEST" button on it? If so, a picture of it would help with certain diagnostics.
- Do you have a GFCI/receptacle - a receptacle with a "TEST" button on it? If so, a picture of it would help with certain diagnostics.
- When you say the breaker won't reset, do you mean: (a) You flip the breaker and it immediately trips/flips again? or (b) You flip the breaker but you still don't get power at the receptacle?

Possible problems include:

- Bad connections at breaker or (more likely) receptacle
- Bad breaker (unlikely, but possible)
- Bad receptacle

but we need more details to figure it out.